# Why is 'null' removed from return type of Document.getElementById in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

VS Code Version:

[image: VS Code Version]

I'm trying some 'Type Narrowing' Code in VS Code, but VS Code gives a different type of information than TypeScript Playground:

VS Code gives:
the return type of `Document.getElementById` is `HTMLElement`:

[image: VS Code]

[image: VS Code]

while TypeScript Playground gives:

the return type of `Document.getElementById` should be `HTMLElement | null`:
[image]

`el` before null checking is expected to be of type `HTMLElement | null`:

[image]

`el` after null checking is expected to be of type `HTMLElement` as type-narrowed:

[image]

I have already upgraded the global typescript package to v4.0.2 and set `typescript.tsdk` to `/Users/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib` in user settings.json

I have set strict type-checking options to:

```json
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true, 
    // "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
```

Is there some configuration I was missing in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: In the status bar at the bottom of VSCode you should see a TypeScript version number. If you click on that you should see a command prompt. One of the options is "Open TSConfig". Can you select that option and verify it points to the correct file?

Comment: @lazytype Thanks, problem solved by creating a tsconfig.json at the root of a project with `strict` set to true.

Comment: If you set `strict: true`, you don't have to specify the individual flags. See here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict

Answer (score 3):

According to [VS Code Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling):

> Typically the first step in any new TypeScript project is to add a `tsconfig.json` file. A `tsconfig.json` file defines the **TypeScript** project **settings**, such as the compiler options and the files that should be included. To do this, open up the **folder** where you want to store your **source** and add a new file named `tsconfig.json`. Once in this file, IntelliSense (Ctrl+Space) will help you along the way.

So, the `tsconfig.json` file should be located in your project's root directory.
Another step to solve your issue is to add `"strict": true` on your newly created `tsconfig.json` file.